# using database routers to shard a table

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to use django's database routers to shard my database, but I am not able to find a solution for that.

I'd like to define two databases, create the same table in both and then save the even rows in one db, the odd ones in the other one. The examples in the documentation show how to write to a master db and to read from the readonly slaves, which is not what I want, because I don't want to store the whole dataset in both dbs.

Do know any webpage explaining what I am trying to do?

Thank you

PS: I am using Postgresql and I know there are tools to achieve the same goal at DB level. My goal is to study if it can also be done in django and to explore if there are some advantages by doing this.

Comment: Can you use the library `django-tenant-schemas` for that?

Comment: I don't see how this could help, multi tenancy and sharding are imho different.

Comment: The documentation covers how you could optionally use multiple databases for write operations:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save